# Typescript - infer property type by a second property type

Tags: typescript, types

I want to define a type `Bar` which is an object with two properties `a` and `foo`.
Property `a` is of type `A` or `B`. The type of property `foo` depends on the type of property `a`. If `a` is of type `A`, then `foo` is of type `(s: AA) => void`. If `a` is of type `B`, then `foo` is of type `(s: BB) => void`. How do I define `Bar`?

For example, assume `type A = string`, `type AA = string`, `type B = number` and `type BB = number`. I would expect the following code to work:

```
const f = ({ a, foo }: Bar): void => {
    if (a === 'abc') {
        foo('def')
    }
}
```

And the following code to show an error:

```
const f = ({ a, foo }: Bar): void => {
    if (a === 'abc') {
        foo(4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union type inside `Bar` and then have the function reference the type like so

```
type Bar = {
    a: string | number,
    foo: (s: Bar['a']) => void
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwFBW1OAuKAZ2AQEsA7AcygB8pyBXAWwCMIEAaLHAMwHs+BABSEC8BAG0A5HCkBdAJQoAfFABufUgBMMAXygYMAYz7liUHiihC0uDhYFRdYxAoIbtK9N2ylLQuBRkVBkWIyklTBxohz4hKS0IHgifJz0gA)

Comment: Interesting. But what if `A` and `AA` are not the same?

Comment: `foo` here is `(s: string | number) => void`, so `{ a: 's', foo(i: string | number) { } }` is a `Bar`, but `{ a: 's', foo(i: string) {} }` is not.

Comment: yes but your solution doesn't work for the case where for example `type A = string`, `type AA = number`, `type B = number` and `type BB = string`.

Comment: This should work even if the types A and AA are different, right? ```const f = ({ a, foo }: Bar): void => {  if (a === 1) { foo('one') }  }``` would have A as a string and AA as a number?

Comment: @jpthesolver2 this solution doesn't work if `A` and `AA` are different, and that's why it doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @jpthesolver2 apparently this solution has a bigger problem. The following works although it shouldn't: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwFBW1OAuKAZ2AQEsA7AcygB8pyBXAWwCMIEAaLHAMwHs+BABSEC8BAG0A5HCkBdAJQoAfFABufUgBMMAXygYMAYz7liUHiihC0uDhYFRdYxAoIbtK9N2ylLQuBRkVBkWIyklTBxohz4hAGYFHyc9DCA